# Using CSS while printing a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The title is a little confusing but basically I have a PHP page with css applied, I use javascript to take a div(form) and print it using the `print()` function just like so.

```
function printform(form){
    var printdata = document.getElementById(form);
    newwin = window.open("");
    newwin.document.write(printdata.outerHTML);
    newwin.print();
    newwin.close();
}
```

The page pops up but I want to use the css of the PHP page which I can't seem to get working.
I have tried using a rel to get the css file (tried the absolute path as well) and delaying the printing but it didn't work (code below).

```
function printform(form){
    var printdata = document.getElementById(form);
    newwin = window.open("");
    newwin.document.write(printdata.outerHTML);
    newwin.document.write('<html><head>');
    newwin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" media=\\"all\\" />');
    newwin.document.write('</head><body >');
    newwin.document.write('</body></html>');
    setTimeout(function(){newwin.print();},1000);
    newwin.focus();
}
```

How can I make the css appear on the other page?

I can give more context if needed.

Comment: Shouldn't `printdata.outerHTML` get written between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags?

Comment: I've tried putting inside the body and it did change much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that your content is in the `body`:

```
function printform(form){
    var printdata = document.getElementById(form);
    newwin = window.open("");
    newwin.document.write('<html><head>');
    newwin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" media=\\"all\\" />');
    newwin.document.write('</head><body >');
    newwin.document.write('</body>' + printdata.outerHTML + '</html>');
    setTimeout(function(){newwin.print();},1000);
    newwin.focus();
}
```

Second, your `media=\\"all\\"` seems to be incorrect, you need to change it to `media="all"` or `media="print"`

Comment: Tried putting the content in the body just like shown and even tried changing it like this:

    newwin.document.write('</head><body >');
    newwin.document.write(printdata.outerHTML + '</body></html>');

Still doesn't do anything about the css

Comment: @gabriel I've confirmed in a test environment that this solution works. Did you fix the "media" attribute? And did you confirm that the style sheet is in a subfolder named "css"? You might also want to try prefixing the CSS path with a slash, e.g. `"/css/css.css"`.